# Как сделать чтобы функция считала символы строки до пробелов? C#

Tags: c#, windows, строки

У меня есть переменная которая содержит текст из текстбокса

```
a = textBox1.Text;9
```

Далее есть небольшой метод, считающий количество букв в строке и выводящий это значение в label1

```
 Console.Write(a.Length);
 label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a.Length);
```

Мне необходимо чтобы эта программа:
1.не считала все буквы в строке, а считала их до пробела.
2.Сохраняла результат до пробела и после него в разные переменные

Помогите пожалуйста сделать хотя бы пункт 1, но с возможностью дальнейшего апгрейда до пункта 2

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
var array = a.Split(' '); // разбиваем исходную строку на подстроки разделителем пробел

var part1 = array[0];
var part2 = array[1];

var len = part1.Length;
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(len);
```

Вам нужно будет самостоятельно обработать ситуацию, когда пробела в строке нет.

Comment: По идее, нужно [`a.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), а то вдруг в строке много пробелов.

Comment: @VladD зависит от задачи :) можно и так сделать

Answer (score 1):

Наверное вам нужно что-то вроде такого

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Hello, World!";
        string s1, s2;
        int n;

        if ((n = s.IndexOf(' ')) != -1)
        {
            s1 = s.Substring(0, n);
            s2 = s.Substring(n + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            s1 = s;
            s2 = "";
        }

        Console.WriteLine("s1 = \"{0}\" with length = {1}, s2 = \"{2}\" with length {3}",
            s1, s1.Length, s2, s2.Length); 
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
s1 = "Hello," with length = 6, s2 = "World!" with length 6
```

Comment: можно обойтись и без string.Copy. Строки же неизменяемые )

Comment: @pavelip  Да, по инерции написал.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Спасибо, а как сделать чтобы  последняя строка выводилась не в консоль а в label1?

Comment: @hello_max Наверное достаточно написать label1.Text = s2;

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать: `int count = a.indexOf(" ");`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?